# Communicating with a Bluetooth device from UEFI code

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, boot, bootloader, uefi

Is it possible to communicate with a mobile device supporting Bluetooth LE from UEFI of a system? UEFI specification 2.6 adds support for Bluetooth but I dont see any new laptops supporting it and also the specification doesnt say anything about Bluetooth LE.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is possible. However, its not related to UEFI Mode but this feature has to be embedded into the bluetooth chip itself. This feature is generally known as **Headless mode** of Bluetooth Chip.

The Bluetooth chips contain two firmwares. One firmware for general BT functionality and the other firmware contain a lite Bluetooth stack which contain a very cut down version of Bluetooth stack which can support BLE feature. So, when your laptop either gets shutdown or goes to sleep, your BT chip goes into headless mode and start advertising itself to other BLE device. Other ble device like mobile can see this and can connect to it and start your laptop.

This feature is however, not present in any laptop known to me. But you find a good example of this in Samsung's smart TV. You can switch on your TV from samsung mobile using ble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to able to communicate with the BLE device from the UEFI mode itself (before the OS boots up)